# Zero Crossing rate

Tags: signal-analysis

Is it possible to have negative zero crossing rate? (can rate be negative?!?)

Because I saw a figure which the signal has been broken in frames each of 10msec, with the plot of zero crossing rate taking negative values, going under the horizontal line.

Also this figure instead of having Zr in the vertical line it has Zc/10msec, maybe thats the reason?

Comment: Usually it is not possible to get negative ZCR.

Comment: You can not get negative values for zero crossing - it seems that you did not get the right interpretation of the graph